# Regular expression split

Tags: python, regex

I have inputs similar to the following:

```
TV-12VX
TV-14JW
TV-2JIS
VC-224X
```

I need to remove everything after the numbers after the dash. The result would be:

```
TV-12
TV-14
TV-2
TV-224
```

How would I do this split via regular expressions?

Comment: Do you want to *split* it, or do you just want to remove it? (That is, do you want to extract them both or just keep the start?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code shows how to match strings of the form "TV-" + (some number):

```
>>> re.match('TV-[0-9]+','TV-12VX').group(0)
'TV-12'
```

(Note that, because I'm using `match`, this only works if the string starts with the bit you want to extract.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex is appropriate for you: `(.+?-\d+?)[a-zA-Z]`. You can use it with `re.findall`, or `re.match`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
p = re.match('([\w]{2}-\d+)', 'TV-12VX')
print(p.group(0))
```

Outputs

```
TV-12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything after the digits with this:

```
re.sub(r"^(\w+-\d+).*", r"\1", input)
```